# How to make python relative imports of a module work in this simple setup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am using Python 3.10.4 and I have the following setup:

```
__init__.py
a.py
child
  __init__.py
  b.py
```

a.py:

```
def add(a,b):
 return a+b
```

b.py:

```
 from ..a import add
 print(add(2,3))
```

**init**.py files are empty.

My issue is that in this setup running python child/b.py from the top level directory here always results in "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

I have tried various suggestions from [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) including trying to append the path using the following but that didn't help :

```
import sys
import os

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))
```

The only way I have been able to make this work is by using an absolute import and exporting the working directory path to PYTHONPATH using `export PYTHONPATH=.`

How do I make relative imports work?

Thanks!

Comment: Running a submodule as a script. This is [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/674039) again.